# Cannot create user, email: invalid!! while trying to create a user

Tags: 7, rules, civicrm

Here is the export of my rule:

```
{ "rules_create_drupal_user" : {
  "LABEL" : "Create Drupal User",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "civicrm" ],
  "ON" : { "civicrm_contact_edit" : [], "civicrm_contact_create" : [] },
  "IF" : [
    { "NOT civicrm_entity_user_exists" : { "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm_contact" ] } }
  ],
  "DO" : [
    { "civicrm_entity_action_create_user" : {
        "USING" : {
          "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm_contact" ],
          "is_active" : "1",
          "notify" : "0",
          "signin" : "0",
          "username_format" : "first last"
        },
        "PROVIDE" : { "civicrm_user" : { "civicrm_user" : "Created Drupal User" } }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

An "Cannot create user, email: invalid!!" error occurs soon after submitting the webform. Drupal user has to be created soon after Civicrm contact is created. After submitting webform as I have used civicrm integration, civicrm contact is created.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rule that fires when civicrm contact is created. It works off Tag, ie the webform adds a Tag to the Contact. Rules then runs off that event. Note this rule also auto logs the person in but you should be able to get some clues from this. You need civicrm_entity module.

```
    { "rules_self_create_user_account_and_login" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create User Account",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "civicrm", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "civicrm_entity_tag_create" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT civicrm_entity_user_exists" : { "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:entity-id-contact" ] } },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:entity-table" ],
          "value" : "civicrm_contact"
        }
      },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:tag-id" ], "value" : "525" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "civicrm_entity_action_create_user" : {
          "USING" : {
            "civicrm_contact" : [ "civicrm-entity-tag:entity-id-contact" ],
            "is_active" : "1",
            "notify" : "1",
            "signin" : "1",
            "username_format" : "email"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "civicrm_user" : { "civicrm_user" : "Created Drupal User" } }
        }
      },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "civicrm\/user?reset=1" } }
    ]
  }
}
```